# MetisMenu not working correctly in IE8/9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

on this page http://jolaga.laohost.net/topsleva I use metisMenu to toggle categories on left. It's work perfectly with one small exception.  In IE8/9 If i click "+" icon, submenu opens but after that if i click again it doesnt hide. Can somebody help me with this issue ?
Also appear some problems with bootstrap in IE8 but I post it in different question.

Answer (score 2):

change jquery.metisMenu.js for this code, working in IE8/9!, the problem is the **collapse** function than work bad in IE, i use **slideUp**, **slideDown** or **slideToggle** of jQuery to solve this.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

var pluginName = "metisMenu",
    defaults = {
        toggle: true
    };

function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {

        var $this = $(this.element),
            $toggle = this.settings.toggle;

        $this.find('li.active').has('ul').children('ul').addClass('metis-open').css('display', 'block');
        $this.find('li').not('.active').has('ul').children('ul').addClass('metis-close').css('display', 'none');

        $this.find('li').has('ul').children('a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active').children('ul').slideToggle().toggleClass('metis-close').toggleClass('metis-open');

            if ($toggle) {
                $(this).parent('li').siblings().removeClass('active').children('ul.metis-open').slideUp().toggleClass('metis-open');
            }
        });
    }
};

$.fn[ pluginName ] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved within the newer version of this plugin for IE8 & IE9

Visit https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu

I am the author of the changes.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in IE8. I find that when I click on the parent li, I have to click three times to see the actual children. Just not sure why it doesn't expand on first click. Any help would be great. I am actually using the latest version of the metisMenu v1.1.3 plugin.

Comment: I am facing this issue in IE8 still as well even using the latest version. Anyone manage to figure this out?

Comment: Hey I'm able to have a working menu without having to click three times. Read through this link: https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu/issues/7 . Basically it says that the cause is not IE8 perse, but rather any browser that doesn't support transitions and that you need to initialize the plugin first.